# crumbled model,

Tags: modeling

im a relatively new user, within a year. I've been modeling a castle and I'm frustrated that one day my modeling all crumbled. ill include a few pics of before and after.

I did some research and the only thing out of the ordinary I did was that I played around with the clip end till it was in the millions and it happened within a day of that. I also imported a model, and maybe that corrupted it.

I switched the clip end back to 2000, and got rid of the model, but still no chang. im really sad, I worked a while on this and its in ruins. is there any way anyone can think of to help me in this.

thanks[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)